# Detect I am running an iPhone application on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am familiar with checking if I am on iPad using    (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad).
But, this is true only for **universal** apps.
I wonder if there is a way to know I am on iPad running an **iPhone** app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]`.

Answer (score -1):

I think even then it gives the right device indication..

As `UIDevice` uses a shared class through out the device, it should give iPad only what ever type of the app is..

Have you tried it.?

As per the apple, and enum defined in `UIDevice` class it is like this

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIUserInterfaceIdiom) {
#if __IPHONE_3_2 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone,           // iPhone and iPod touch style UI
UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad,             // iPad style UI
#endif
};
```

Here you can see that it enum just gives the which style of UI it is using, as it is iPhone app running in iPhone style UI it gives as `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone`

And also the name itself says that `UserInterfaceIdiom` it means it relate to UI screen size.

Instead you can use

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
```

Which gives the exact device model, here you can check for range of string "iPad" to identify the device.

Comment: Yes, I tried and (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) is false when it's an iPhone app running on iPad.